# Cannot resize table using CSS (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

NOTICE: I posted this question in the Wordpress forum but was directed to this site as it dealt with CSS. Please refrain from telling me this does not belong here as I have no other options. Thanks. : )

I am using a Responsive Wordpress theme and have been loving it so far. I've uploaded some XML data through the WP Import All plugin into a table and it's working perfectly! However I can't seem to change the height/width on the table itself, the table data or rows. I've created a child theme and all my other CSS is working fine. Here is the code I have. The 40px is just a random number to test if it is working.

```
table{
    text-align: right;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:9px;
    width: 40px;
}
th{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

This is what the Responsive theme CSS table styles looks like. I have not modified it just created a child theme.

```
/* =Tables
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
th,
td,
table {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Whenever I refresh the page the table stays exactly the same. I can change the font size, background etc. but not the size. Any help would be wonderful! Thanks for the time.

Comment: Are you loading your custom styles in after the theme styles?

Comment: @monners Yes. I believe so. I created the child theme and then applied it to my site. I have been editing only in the child theme. Is there a way to load the custom style first or is this even needed?

Comment: Load your `child theme` after everything else. Perhaps the default is overriding your styling.

Comment: Have you used a tool like Firebug for Firefox or Chromes Developer Tools to see what styles are being applied to your table? If not, start there, it will show you what styles are being applied and what is being overiden. You may also need to get your head around CSS Specificity rules http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/